# Display custom text on phone using asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

Is it possible to display an custom text on a client phone using asterisk. For example depending on a incoming calling rule?

What I want to do is showing different labels on my phone depending on which number extension the caller uses.

I'm currently using asterisk 1.8 and a Grandstream Sip-Phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can change callerid Name part.

If you are using freepbx, that can be done in inbound route or in queue configuration(as prefix)